# Why use semi-gradient instead of full gradient in RL problems, when using function approximation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, dqn, deep-rl, function-approximation

Semi-gradient methods work well in reinforcement learning, but what is there a reason of **not** using the true gradient if it can be computed?

I tried it on the cart pole problem with a deep Q-network and it performed much worse than traditional semi-gradient. Is there a concrete reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Just so that this could be useful for people who refer to this post later on: Please refer to Sutton's reinforcement learning book (2nd edition) example 11.2. It provides an example for why full gradient wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Semi gradient methods work well in **Reinforcement Learning**, but what is the reason of ***not using*** the true gradient if it can be computed?

Just complexity and extra computation, in many cases for a marginal benefit.

> I tried it on the cart pole problem with a deep Q-Network and it performed much worse than traditional semi gradient, is there a concrete reason for this?

It is hard to tell, without exploring the implementation in detail. However, DQN is an inherently unstable learning technique that needs care in choosing hyper-parameters that control this instability and offset against learning rate:

- size of minibatch to train from experience replay on each step
- number of training steps between taking frozen copies for estimation*
- whether or not you use double-learning to avoid maximisation bias (more important if you have fine-grained discretisation of continuous action space)

There is a chance that the optimal choices here are different between true gradient and semi gradient approaches.

* The frozen estimator could be a big clue here in your implementation. If you are using this frozen copy technique, it has a big impact on how you should calculate the true gradient, because changing the parameters would no longer change the current TD target - which is what the true gradient approach fixes. However, getting rid of this stability-improving addition in order to get true gradients might on balance make the algorithm less stable - you could try to fix that by taking larger mini-batches.